# Allowing the user a sandboxed version of a programming language

Tags: user-input, sandbox

*Note: I'd appreciate some tag suggestions for this one..*

I'd like to provide my users with a method of programmatically manipulating data on the server.  This would be done by using an in-browser code editor to be executed at a later date, not dissimilar to the manner https://www.onx.ms employ.

I'd like to avoid writing a DSL (a barrier to adoption?), and would prefer the language that the user writes to be either JavaScript or Ruby based.

My obvious concern is security.  I understand the perils of allowing user generated code to run server-side, but what steps can I take to eliminate the risk?

Do sites like http://railsforzombies.com actually use `irb`, or is it far simpler than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider Java (or other JVM languages such as JRuby, Scala, Clojure etc)? If so - there is a wealth of power in the JVM to restrict the privileges of a sandboxed app. See this other question for details: [How do I create a Java sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715036/how-do-i-create-a-java-sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

[Google Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) lets you safely embed user-specified Javascript in your website, but I think it might be aimed at running the code in the user's browser rather than on your server. I haven't used it myself.

I don't know if there are ready-made solutions for other languages, but I think a custom solution would involve recompiling the interpreter yourself after removing all API libraries that allow the user to write to disk, open network connections, fork processes/threads, and do any other dangerous or denial-of-service operation. Whitelisting "safe" libraries is the only approach that could work for that.

It would be safer if you had separate virtual servers for individual users.

Comment: Caja doesn't sandbox against denial of service attacks. It has no defense against a user running an eternal `while(true){}` loop or allocating lots of memory. Javascript in a sandboxed iframe has the same security guarantees (and lack of dos protection) as Caja while being simpler to use and more standard.