# Running some java code inside its own JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I got a small question: (How) can I run some java code (preferable a jar) in its own JVM, in best case specifying my own libs. So for example to sandbox all file system access.

What of this stuff is possible, and how?

Comment: Do you mean "running some java code" within its own VM started from other Java code ?

Comment: yes, I want to run some java code in a sandbox launched and controlled from java

Comment: Its entirely possible. You will have to write the code though. It involves (optionally) writing your own classloader, installing a security manager, and defining a set of policy files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715036/how-do-i-create-a-java-sandbox

Comment: Yes,a customed classloader

Comment: oh wow, that was fast :D actually never asked a question here before, so i had no idea how fast you get replys here :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit access to the file system or any other resource, make use of Java's [Security Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/index.html for information on how to configure a policy.