# how to build an online compiler without compiling code on my own server

Tags: java, web-services, online-compilation

Part of my final project needs to build a online compiler which can be accessed by everyone. I've implemented the editor part, the main problem is in the compiler part. First I thought I can compile code on university's server, and I asked IT support of my university for help. They refused for security risk (of course).

So, I can't compile code myself.

Then I am thinking of embed a online ide in my website. But service of ideone.com is not free now and I will only run this website for at most 3 weeks, and unfortunately, ideone.com is the only online compiler I know, which provides its API and service.

So, what should I do now?

1. buy service from ideone.com
2. buy a vps service maybe? But I am not sure if they allow me to compile arbitrary java program.
3. ide.com says: "If you represent an educational organization or a small startup initiative (not supported by any company), we are happy to offer you a free MINI package". 
   Or maybe I should try to apply for a mini package? Although I've got no idea what is "mini package".
4. or if you have any other idea, please tell me!!!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to only compile, or both compile and run?

Comment: Both compile and run. I need to show the running result or error in my webpage.

Comment: You can also make your own server. Amazon AWS provides some cheap services that would contain everything you need. Also you could just run it on your computer and use a service to give your computer a host name, one i know of is http://dyn.com/dns/ .

Comment: Heres a link to Tomcat with Amazon AWS [Cat in the Cloud](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-basic.html)

Comment: Thanks for providing these information, I am not quite clear about Amazon AWS and what should I do after I bought this service, I think I need sometime to read them.

Comment: @user3794582: Using AWS is a lot like using a VPS or dedicated server. But it's a lot easier to spin up new instances if old ones get compromised. (Not an excuse for *letting* them get compromised...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2) buy a vps service maybe? But I am not sure if they allow me to compile arbitrary java program

If you buy a VPS or dedicated server, you can usually do whatever you want. But then you're laying yourself open to the same security risks that your university IT department refused to take: If the program does something malicious, and you compile and run it in your VPS/dedicated server, it can do something malicious in your dedicated server.

You can mitigate that a bit by compiling and running the code within your own [`SecurityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) implementation ([more in this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715036/how-do-i-create-a-java-sandbox)), which can prevent (for instance) arbitrary file access, network access, etc.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Is it possible for me to

Comment: compile the code on client's side? I am not sure if there are any way to impliment this, I am just trying to think about new ideas.