# Java block Runtime.exec()?

Tags: java

I noticed that one of my clients has tried to gain shell access to one of my main servers by using Runtime.exec(). Is there a way for me to block this using Java Security Manager?

Comment: while i think Java has Security Manager so that you grant/revoke permission to your client  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.  `Process.start()` uses `SecurityManager.checkExec(cmd)` to check if the operation is permitted.  The javadoc for that method says:

> *"This method calls `checkPermission` with the `FilePermission(cmd, "execute")` permission if `cmd` is an absolute path, otherwise it calls `checkPermission` with `FilePermission("<<ALL FILES>>", "execute")`."*

So you need to configure your security sandbox to block those permissions.  You probably need to block a number of other things too.

This Q&A is a good starting point on how to set up a sandbox:

- [How do I create a Java sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715036/how-do-i-create-a-java-sandbox)

It includes a link to the Oracle documentation ... and it is important that you read and understand that.

Running other peoples' code on your server is potentially dangerous, and you need to understand *how* they could "hurt" you before you can protect against it.  Bear in mind that you *could* be dealing with really smart people ... not just "script kiddies" probing known vulnerabilities.