# Creating program that can run unchecked or faulty piece of code

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create a project in which I will face a problem:

Program will run uncheck code (implementation of given interface). I suspect some of implementation will be broken, they can throw errors, use to many time, memory, even permissions to files. I suppose I should run them with separate thread and kill the thread if it step out of some arbitrary boundaries.

How can I create such program? I am Java developer, but I do not know any Java tools that allow my to analyze thread variables like memory. What are languages and framework that whould help me create such a project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i create a java sandbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715036/how-do-i-create-a-java-sandbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For permissioning things like thread/file access and such I would look into the Java SecurityManager: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html

Without more details on the cases you'd like to stop, I can't really provide much else.